# fortran segmentation fault when OMP_NUM_THREADS bigger than 1

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, openmp, slurm

so im executing `a.out` (compiled fortran code) with the following `runaout.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --time=00:15:00
#SBATCH --job-name=mhsw9
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --nodelist=komputasi09
whoami
hostname
ulimit -s unlimited
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=128
echo "9"
ulimit -s unlimited
/a.out
```

i tried changing OMP_NUM_THREADS to any value bigger than 1. i tried 2, 64, 128, but all segmentation fault. in the code i already set ulimit -s unlimited, but still segmentation fault. i use

```
gfortran -fopenmp assignment1.f90
```

to compile the fortran code. Below is the assignment1.f90 code, the code is running matmul calculation

```
program sample3
use omp_lib
implicit real(8)(a-h,o-z)
parameter (n=8192)
real(8) a(n,n),b(n,n),c(n,n)
real*8 t1,t2
a=0.0d0
call random_number(b)
call random_number(c)
write(6,50) ' Matrix Size =',n
50 format(1x,a,i5)
t1=omp_get_wtime()
!$OMP parallel do reduction(+:a)
do j=1,n
do k=1,n
do i=1,n
    a(i,j)=a(i,j)+b(i,k)*c(k,j)
enddo
enddo
enddo
!$OMP end parallel do
t2=omp_get_wtime()
write(6,60)'Execution Time = ',t2-t1,' sec','A(n,n) = ',a(n,n)
60 format(1x,a,f10.3,a,1x,a,d24.15)
stop
end
```

what confuses me even more is that my friend running the same exact code didn't encounter segmentation fault. can anyone help me please ? where did i do wrong ?

i execute the file using slurm

```
sbatch runaout.sh
```

Comment: No `Implicit None` you fail the assignment. Fix that first. Do you drive without wearing a safety belt? Also I strongly suggest you compile as `gfortran -Wall -Wextra -std=f2018 -fcheck=all -O -g ...` and fix any warnings/errors reported.

Comment: After that I suggest you search the site, this is a duplicate. The best way to solve it almost certainly be to change those large arrays to `Allocatable` ones, but due to the lack of Implicit None I haven't read the code in detail

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure precisely where is the problem, but this code has a number of bad practices (some of them already pointed by @IanBush):

- `implicit none` should be used and all variables explicitely declared
- `real*8` is non standard and `real(8)` is not portable. Use `double precision` instead, or:

```
integer, parameter :: dp=kind(1d0)
real(dp) :: ...
```

- Your arrays are about 800 MB each. Although it is possible to declare such large arrays the way you do (*), it's generally preferable to declare them allocatable:

```
real(dp) :: a(:,:)
...
allocate( a(n,n) )
```

- A reduction on such a large array is a bad idea: under the hood, each thread will have create a full copy of the array. Not only the performances will be terrible, but a lot of memory will be needed (128 threads -> about 100GB needed)
- The point here is that you don't need any reduction at all, since there's no race condition on `a(:,:)` in your parallel code.
- Your compilation command line is neither adapted for debugging (it should be something like `gfortran -Wall -fcheck=all -O -g -fopenmp`), nor for performances (`gfortran -O3 -fopenmp` at least)

(*) I have tested your code with gfortran, and the static declarations of your code are OK as long as the code is compiled without OpenMP. As soon as OpenMP is involved it results in segfaults, even without reduction and a single thread. Making the arrays `allocatable` fixes the problem, but I can't really explain why.

Comment: The answer is sort of in the left had corner of your screen. `ulimit -s unlimited` *might* solve/hide the problem as might using the appropriate OpenMP ICV (OPENMP_STACKSIZE I think but would have to check). But all of lack of implicit none, use of real(8) and real*8 and not using allocatables would cause a student of mine to fail this assignment - as would $omp paralllel do , it is absolutely fundamental in OMP to understand the separate thread creation and worksharing stages in OpenMP, short cuts cloud this understanding (and are an unfortunate inclusion in the spec IMO )

Comment: The reason of the segfault is unclear. Without reduction, OpenMP has no reason to create any hidden temporary array, and as a matter of fact the segfault happens before any instruction, but rather just because of the large static arrays. The large static arrays are not an issue if the code is compiled without OpenMP. unlimiting the stack size did not fix the issue in my tests (on macOS). The behavior may be different with another compiler and/or another OS.

Comment: Not disagreeing in the detail, all I'm saying is that in a typical implementation this kind of error observed with OMP is typically due to insufficient stack space, hence all the "might"s in my comment. The exact cause I don't know, and to be honest don't care about, just learn not to statically allocate large objects as a matter of good practice.

Comment: We have many similar questions. Not sure if this is the first one with array reduction or not, but other typical causes are `threadprivate` or just `private`, sometimes there is no explicit privatisation at all and the array is used as `shared` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011472/segmentation-fault-with-openmp-in-fortran-90-program The message for me is **use allocatable**. For others it is to play with stack size using ulimit and hope for the best (Good luck on MS Windows...).